# Ruby .sub! method on an element in array of strings yields unexpected results

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, methods

I am trying to use .sub! on an element in an array of strings, and get "weird" results.
This is both in 1.8.7 & in 2.1.5
Look at irb log. .sub! does not do what I expect it, but .sub does, and for the original value...

```
irb(main):001:0> k = ['1','2']
=> ["1", "2"]
irb(main):002:0> k[-1].sub!( /(\d+)/, (($1).to_i + 1 ).to_s() )
=> "1"
irb(main):003:0> k
=> ["1", "1"]
irb(main):004:0> k[-1] = k[-1].sub( /(\d+)/, (($1).to_i + 1 ).to_s() )
=> "3"
irb(main):005:0> k
=> ["1", "3"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with `sub` vs `sub!`.

In the first expression, `$1` is referencing the first capture of the *previous* regex that got matched. Which means, in this case, that it's probably nil, which then becomes 0, to which you add 1.

In the second expression, `$1` is again referencing the first capture, i.e. 2. If you run the line again, it'll be holding 1 and you'll get an unexpected result.

On that note, what you seem to be looking for is a block:

```
k[-1].sub!(/\d+/) { |i| (i.to_i + 1).to_s }
```

Comment: Now to the next question, what happens if the regular expression has some beackreferences? I have put here a simple example, but I may want to access just the backreferenc value...

Comment: In a substitution string you can use \1, \2, etc.: `sub(/\d+/, "\0")`. I'd advise to ask a separate question though.